# Getting the bound $\frac{1}{h}\int_0^{T-h}\int_t^{t+h}\int_\Omega |\nabla u(\tau)| |\nabla u(t+h) - \nabla u(t)|\;dxd\tau dt \leq C$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega)).$

Is it possible to find the following bound:
$$\frac{1}{h}\int_0^{T-h}\int_t^{t+h}\int_\Omega |\nabla u(\tau,x)| |\nabla u(t+h,x) - \nabla u(t,x)|\;dxd\tau dt \leq C\quad \forall h \in [0,T]$$
where $C$ is allowed to depend on (appropriate norms of) $u$ but should not depend on $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no information about how $\nabla u$ changes with respect to $t$, we can't hope to obtain any cancellation in $|\nabla u(t+h,x) - \nabla u(t,x)|$. Just estimate it by $|\nabla u(t+h,x)| + |\nabla u(t,x)|$.

Using the notation $U(t) = \|\nabla u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2}$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we estimate the given integral by
$$\frac{1}{h} \int_0^{T-h} \int_t^{t+h} U(\tau) (U(t+h)+U(t))\,d\tau\,dt
\tag{1}$$
Since $U\in L^2(0,T)$, its one-sided Hardy-Littlewood maximal function 
$$ M_U(x) = \sup_{h>0} \frac{1}{h}  \int_t^{t+h} U(\tau)  \,d\tau $$
 is also in $L^2(0,T)$ (with an appropriate [norm bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function)). Thus, (1) is estimated by 
$$ \int_0^{T-h}  M_U(t) (U(t+h)+U(t)) \,dt$$ which is integral of the  product of two $L^2$ functions, hence finite.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get in (1) the product of two integrals over $\Omega$ from what I had in my OP?

Comment: (I still couldn't figure out how you got (1)). I think instead one can use Holder's inequality and then if we define $U=\lVert \nabla u(\tau) \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$, it should still work unless I made a amistake.

Comment: @maximumtag You are right. I changed the definition of $U$.